# Nodejs mqtt client cannot connect to mosquitto broker configured with a trusted CA

Tags: node.js, ssl, mqtt

I have configured the Mosquitto broker using trusted CA certificates (Go Daddy). I can connect to it using MQTT box over wss as well as mqtts by setting "SSL / TLS Certificate Type" to "CA signed server certificate". But when I try to connect using an mqtt-client using nodejs it gives the following error :

"**unable to verify the first certificate**". 
Error Code: "**UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE**"

I have checked my npm config file. The "ca" key is set to null which means it will refer to the root certificates in its store, but still not able to connect.

code:

```
let MQTT = require('mqtt');
const options = {
    port: 8883,
    clientId: "test_POC",
    protocol: 'mqtts',

}

let client = MQTT.connect('mqtts://xxxx.com',options);

client.on("connect", ()=>{
    console.log("Connected to broker "+ client.clientId);
    publishToTopic("test_poc", "Hi!");
});

client.on("error", (error)=>{
    console.log("Can't connect " + error);
});
```

Comment: Edit the question to include all of the actual error, also which CA has signed your certificate?

Comment: Have highlighted the error. The certificate was purchased from GoDaddy

Comment: There isn't really enough to go on here, you're going to have to dig into what the broker is presenting using something like `openssl s_client`

Comment: On debugging more i stumbled upon the error code: "UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE".